# PHP & MongoDB: Building a custom query with multiple values per field

Tags: php, mongodb

Initially, I built a mongo query in php using by using a nested associative array. Then I call:

```
$collection->find($query, $fields)
```

However, I cannot do that as far as I know when there needs to be the same field name repeated at the same level. For example:

```
{"field1" : "value1", "field1" : "value2"}
```

Is there another way to structure queries in php, or another way I can write this example query so that I don't have multiple of the same field in the same level?

Comment: something like `['field1' => ['$in' => ['value1', 'value2']]]` would work I think for you, that is of course an or statement but I think that's what you are looking for in reality.

Comment: @Sammaye That works! Thanks!